# Matplotlib: formatting text without LaTeX

Tags: python, matplotlib, latex, text-formatting

I want to add a text box to a matplotlib plot in Python. The first line of text has to be in bold font and the second one has to be underlined. So far, I only managed to make it work by using LaTeX, in the following way:

```
pylab.text(120, 200, r'\textbf{' + str(label['1000'][0]) + '}\n' + '\underline{' + str(label['1000'][1]) + '}', **alignment)
```

with

```
rc('text', usetex = True)
```

However, this makes the script dependent on LaTeX installation, which I would prefer to avoid in order to make it more easily usable by less expert users.

Is there any way to accomplish it?

Thank you!